# setInterval are clearing after 2 times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

i'm making a script that contains a loop animation for my team sites. But the `Interval` are stopping after 2 times calling the function!

Look the code:

```js
function loopSites() {
  if ($(".site").attr("style") == "display: none;") {
    if ($(" #0").hasClass("espro")) {
      $("#0").fadeOut(500);
      $("#0").removeClass("espro");
      $("#0").addClass("espra");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#0").html($("#espra"));
      }, 500);
      $("#0").fadeIn();
    } else if ($("#0").hasClass("espra")) {
      $("#0").fadeOut(500);
      $("#0").removeClass("espra");
      $("#0").addClass("espro");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#0").html($("#espro"));
      }, 500);
      $("#0").fadeIn();
    }
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var interval = setInterval(loopSites, 2000);
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $(".site").hide();
      $("#0").addClass("espro");
      interval;
    } else if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
      $(".site").fadeIn();
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  });
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $(".site").hide();
    $("#0").addClass("espro");
    interval;
  } else {
    $(".site").fadeIn();
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section3">
  <div class="ui vertical masthead center aligned segment">
    <div class="ui text container">
      <h1 class="ui inverted header">
        <b>My beatiful text</b>
      </h1>
      <div class="ui stackable grid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="eight wide column" id="0"></div>
          <div class="eight wide column site" id="1">
            <center id="espro">
              <a href="">
                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/espratings/image/upload/v1505946374/20638341_1631615206869494_6172662154381413393_n_qekvgh.png" alt="" class="ui circular image">
                <h3>fb page</h3>
                <p>fb page description</p>
              </a>
            </center>
          </div>
          <div class="eight wide column site" id="2">
            <center id="espra">
              <a href="">
                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/espratings/image/upload/v1505946374/20638341_1631615206869494_6172662154381413393_n_qekvgh.png" alt="" class="ui circular image">
                <h3>my beatiful site hehe</h3>
                <p>description of my site</p>
              </a>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

What i'm making wrong? And how to make the script shorter? Any hints are welcome!

Comment: you should look into requestAnimationFrame instead of using setInterval for animations

Comment: `interval;` isn't doing anything in your code.

Comment: @Dehli why not? he print this on console when called: http://prntscr.com/gnphqi

Comment: @SampaioLeal that variable is just the identifier of the interval you set above. It does not set an interval like you are trying to do. You will have to create a new interval be using `setInterval(loopSites, 2000)` to start the interval again

Comment: @JulianSoro where i put the requestAnimationFrame with the callback to loopSites?

Comment: "But the Interval are stopping after 2 times " is not true. interval is not cleared and it keeps running as expected. Add console log and see

Comment: @spiritwalker do you see the code snippet? do you run it?

Comment: @SampaioLeal Yes I did run you code https://jsfiddle.net/spiritwalker/70jcc9we/ check the console log

Comment: check the comments on the answer of Averyefbehifbwei, i found the issue

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval function will run and it will call the function `loopSites` and it will display the two things. Then you clear the interval right away. You need to not clear the interval if you want it to continue going.

Also calling `interval` does nothing. The interval variable is just an integer identification number used to cancel the interval. If you want to recreate the interval you have to use `setInterval(loopSites, 2000);` again.

I would suggest checking out this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Also if you are trying to draw things on the screen, I suggest using requestAnimationFrame: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: commenting the first paragraph of your answer: the clearInterval() is called when the width of the browser is less than 768. but when the width is more than 768, the script dont call the clearInterval()

Comment: look in the 7 line of the script, i use setTimeout to fadeOut the div. simple.

Comment: Please verify for me using a console.log that any of the blocks that a clearInterval is in, is not being called.

Comment: look: http://prntscr.com/gnplaw ; and the console: http://prntscr.com/gnplnz ; and the verbose logs: http://prntscr.com/gnplx4

Comment: Console.log right before the if statement in the loopSites function

Comment: like i think: http://prntscr.com/gnpo61 the function is executed
code: http://prntscr.com/gnpof5

Comment: Delete the extra space one `if ($(" #0").hasClass("espro")) {`

Comment: i found the error. when the script change the class of the #0 element, he clear the #1 and #2 on #section3 http://prntscr.com/gnprrt